# PowerPoint charts. Different series type within series with another type

Tags: c#, .net, charts, powerpoint, openxml

I have bubble chart with 4 series. I need to add to this primary axis one more series, that should be line. I need it as "helper" line. I know that I can add it as secondary axis, but it is not appropriate to me. Does someone know is it possible to have differet types of series on the one axis and if yes - how it can be done?

I also tryed to do such thing in PowerPoint, not in code, but didn't have any good result. If someone knows how to do this in Office manually, please, share, this info will also help!)

Comment: Create a presentation with whatever content you wanted to create in OpenXML, then use the [OpenXML Productivity Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5124) to see how the file would be generated with code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I made some investigation.
The answers for the question is no. But this is true only for bubble charts. We cannot change bubble series to line series, for example, because data format is not the same. Bubble series is a point (X, Y, Value - diameter). **Not** list of points. Line series is a **list** of points (X, Y). Data formats are completely different. But the goood news is that we **can** change series type from line to bar, for example, because they have the same data format.